# How to use jQuery accordion menu with multiple submit button?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have JSP page with accordion menu. I have five menu with each have seperate submit buttons. How to post the data from each submit button?

Comment: So, you have a single form with many submit buttons? I'm not quite understanding what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put the entire accordion in a single `<form>`. I.e. do not do

```
<form>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
        <div>First form</div>
        <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
        <div>Second form</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But just give each accordion section their own `<form>`. I.e. rather do

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div><form>First form</form></div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div><form>Second form</form></div>
</div>
```

This way each button has its own `<form>` where you can speficy a specific `action`.

This is by the way unrelated to Java/JSP. It's just basic HTML knowledge.